# D language: how do you do such as Php array(); foreach()?

Tags: php, d

How can i do this $array and $object and foreach() interpretation from Php to D correctly?

Php (pro):

```
class Zend_Models
{
    public static function getSome()
    {
      $array = array(
         "a" => "b",
         "b" => "b"
      );
      $object = (object) $array;

      foreach($object as $value)
      {
        $this->view->inject[] = $value;              
      }
      // Zend_Debug::dump($this->view->inject); 
      return "ok";
    }


    public static getAbove() 
    {
      return self::getSome();
    }
}
```

D (incubator, doing mistakes):

```
import std.stdio;

class Zend_Models
{
  void static getSome()
  {
    //?...
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't know D, but from the looks of it, it isn't a dynamic language like PHP. You will need to use some HashTable class or something similar.

Comment: Then it would be useless learning a new languages to minimize simplicity no? Must be more smarter way then PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
import std.stdio;

class Zend_Models
{
    string getSome()
    {
          auto array = ["a", "b"];

          foreach(value; array)
          {
              this.view.inject ~= value;
          }

          return "ok";
       } 
    }

    string getAbove() {
        return getSome();
    }
}
```

That said, you probably shouldn't try to write PHP in D.  It's probably better to use exceptions than to return a status code, and if you do return a status code, an [enum](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/enum.html) is probably better than a string.